# Google Analytics does not show yesterday's statistics immediately

Tags: google-analytics

Every morning when I check my Google Analytics statistics it seems as if there was a massive drop in visitors yesterday.

Here's the graph at 9:40AM:
[image]

At some point during the day, all of a sudden it apparently has processed the data (which is not a lot as I have around 2K visitors a day) and shows the actual numbers.

At 10:58 it's updated and shows:
[image]

I want to be able to see my stats from yesterday morning to midnight when I access my analytics in the morning. I find it hard to believe Google needs 10+ hours to process the little data I have.

I've already looked under property settings and I've set my "Reporting time zone" to my own country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just the way that Google Analytics works.  I've been using it for years and I usually see this.  Occasionally it will get two or even three day behind in the processing.

There is nothing I know of that you can do to improve this situation.  There is no setting for it. You just need to wait until Google's processing is complete before yesterday's numbers are finalized.